# I want a thin transparent div line separator. How to do this in CSS/html?

Tags: html, css, border

Basically I want a line like the ones that separate posts on stackoverflow, only I want it vertical and to be a kind of "left border" that will be in a separate div to display links and content. So instead of making a big rectangle on the left side with links and text, I just want like a really thin, subtle gray line that goes all the way down the page.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
.some-class
{
    border-left:1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.thin_border {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#mydiv {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will be a semi-transparent border on the left of the element.

The height depends on the height of the parent element.

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="thin_border">
content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to use:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="vertical-line"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.vertical-line {
   width: 1px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #696969;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can then customize the color, attributes, height design of this vertical line by modifying this `.vertical-line` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Checking at the CSS of this page I could see that this is the CSS used:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
```

You could do something like this:

```
border-right: 1px solid #cccccc,
widht: 1px;
height: //depends on how tall you want it
```

Comment: He said all the way down the page, so maybe `height: 100%;`?

Comment: Oh, missed that, but yes, that would do.